# Variables not defined inside function on second time at foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Considering all this files :

vars.php

```
if($local){
    $var = 'var';
    $foo = 'foo';
    $var1 = 'var1';
    $foo1 = 'foo1';
}else{
    $var = '';
    $foo = '';
    $var1 = '';
    $foo1 = '';
}

/remote/vars.remote.php is the same as vars.php but different values for variables
```

cons.php

```
 $local = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1') ? 1 : 0;
 if ($local){
      include_once ('vars.php');
 }else{
       include_once('/remote/vars.remote.php);
 }    
 define(CONST_OP_1,$var);
 define(CONST_MAIL_1,$foo);
 define(CONST_OP_2,$var1);
 define(CONST_MAIL_2,$foo1);
```

config.php

```
 require_once "Mail/Queue.php"; 
 include_once ('cons.php');
 $db_options['user'] = CONST_OP_1;
 $db_options['pass'] = CONST_OP_2;
 $mail_options['port'] = CONST_MAIL_1;
 $mail_options['dsn'] = CONST_MAIL_2;
```

mail.php

```
 class Sendmail
   {
 ...
function sendc($var){
      require_once ('config.php');
      $mail_queue = new Mail_Queue( $db_options , $mail_options );
 }

...

}
```

comm.php

```
 foreach($array_mails as $email){
    $mail_q =  $sendmail->sendc($u_name);
}
```

There is something I do not understand and I'm not able to figured this out why it happens . when I execute `comm.php` with and `ajax function` I pass and array in `$array_mails` but for a strange reason to me , everything work just fine at the first loop but at second loop (and following)  at the foreach it seem that arrays inside `config.php` file does not seem to be declared so it give me a

> NOTICE: undefined variables for $db_options and $mail_options.

I know how to fix this but I would like to understand why is this happens. Can anyone explain please ?

Comment: I am not sure but what happens when you replace `? 1: 0` with `? true : false` in the part of the code that is setting the value for `$local` variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `require_once('config.php')` to a `require`, or alternatively place it at the top of the file.

`require_once` only allows the file to be included a single time, so it doesn't include it again for the second loop.

Comment: ok , thanks Syfaro but the documentation said http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php "will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again"  meaning one time was include so my variables are there once which is enough. Am I the only one who understood this way?

Comment: I'd imagine that when you require it, it only includes those values at that scope so on the next loop, they're lost. If you put it at the top of the file, this wouldn't happen.