# how to call other class object to another class fnction using PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, database-connection

I am acing one issue. I need to pass one class object to another class function using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

> db.php:

```
class DBOperations{
    // constructor
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function prepare_param(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}
$dbo = new DBOperations();
```

> newclass.php:

```
require_once('db.php');
class DBhandler
{

    function __construct()
    {

    }
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function select_all_profile(){
        $output=$dbo->prepare_param();
    }
}
$dbh = new DBhandler();
print_r($dbh->select_all_profile());exit;
```

Here I need to pass the `DBOperations` object(`i.e-$dbo`) to the `DBhandler` class function to execute the first class function which is not happening. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it giving any errors ?

Comment: You are passing it correctly. Is there any errors? Have you turned on error reporting? `DBOperations` does not have `connect()` function that you are calling in constructor.

Comment: yes, its `Notice: Undefined variable: dbo`.

Comment: But your updated question is not passing `dbo` variable now.

Comment: Yes, If I have Already included the page and inside the public function of second class I can not access the first first class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common construct for this would pass the DBOperations value into the constructor of the DBhandler class as it can be re-used several times.  This is commonly called Dependency Injection (DI) and used to configure classes with any dependencies rather than them being created in each class.

```
require_once('db.php');
class DBhandler
{
    private $dbo;
    function __construct( $dbo )
    {
        $this->dbo = $dbo;
    }
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function select_all_profile(){
        $output=$this->dbo->prepare_param();
    }
}
$dbh = new DBhandler($dbo);
print_r($dbh->select_all_profile());
exit;
```

Comment: Have you tested it ? Its throwing `Warning: Missing argument 1 for DBhandler::__construct(),`.

Comment: This should be the `$dbo` value in `$dbh = new DBhandler($dbo);`

Answer (score 0):

Require_once may not work correctly inside repetitive function when storing variable.

To make sure variable bar available at each function call, replace require once with require. eg situation: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898199/variables-not-defined-inside-function-on-second-time-at-foreach)

Comment: No,same issue after changing as per you also.

Comment: Already include the page and inside the public function of second class I can not access the first first class object.

Answer (score 0):

TRIED & TESTED.

1st: the line `$this->connect();` in 1st class will give error.

```
<?php
class DBOperations{
    // constructor
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        //$this->connect();  // I have commented it out.
    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function prepare_param(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}
$dbo = new DBOperations();

class DBhandler
{

    function __construct()
    {

    }
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function select_all_profile($dbo){
        $output=$dbo->prepare_param();
    }
}
$dbh = new DBhandler();
print_r($dbh->select_all_profile($dbo));exit;  // This will print 'test'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the variable scope issue. You instantiate `DBOperations()` in db.php but this variable will not be available in a class in another file.

You should really do better instantiation rather than just in the file, but to fix your issue pass in the `DBOperations` object into `DBhandler()`.

> db.php:

```
class DBOperations{

    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function prepare_param(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}
$dbo = new DBOperations();
```

> newclass.php:

```
require_once('db.php');

class DBhandler
{
    private $dbo;

    function __construct(DBOperations $dbo)
    {
        $this->dbo = $dbo;
    }

    public function select_all_profile(){
        $output = $this->dbo->prepare_param();
    }
}
$dbh = new DBhandler($dbo);
print_r($dbh->select_all_profile());exit;
```